# Is it possible to pass boolean true/false (as opposed to 1/0) into MariaDB with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've recently done a new server install, and it seems on the old one I had `sql_mode=''` in my `my.cnf` file.  I've removed that now, so I have the default `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and the other default options.

Sadly though, that STT declaration is breaking my php PDO code where I explicity force type on my booleans, and send `true`/`false` through to the database.

I guess before these were being silently converted to `1`/`0`.

Are these my only options:

1. change my PHP variables ($isArchived etc) from the semantic niceness of `true`/`false` to `1`/`0`.
2. reinstate `sql_mode = ''`

Or am I missing something?  My columns are defined as tinyint(1) - that used to be the best we could do with MySQL, and I don't THINK there's a boolean type, even now.  What's the best practice?  Thank you!

**edit:**

I realise now it's just `false` it fails on.  It happily converts `true` to `1`, but for some reason sees `false` as `''` and balks.  Could this be a problem in my PHP code rather than MySQL...

Comment: In MySQL TRUE is an alias of 1 and FALSE is an alias of 0. This is documented. If some problem occures it can be (1) you transfer them as string literals, not keywords (2) client-side issue.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion, so am trying a different question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874468/i-think-pdo-is-converting-my-boolfalse-param-to-string-am-i-going-mad